# Flask testing routes - not registered

Tags: python, flask

I've a very basic Flask application:

```
#main.py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/sth/')
def hi():
    return 'HI\n'
```

and I try to test the existence of the url, however, to me it seems the routes are not registered:

```
#tests/test_view.py
from flask import Flask

class TestSthView:
    def test_sth_returns_ok(self):
        app = Flask(__name__)
        c = app.test_client()
        resp = c.get('/sth/')

        assert resp.request.path == '/sth/'
        assert resp.status_code == 200
```

.

Could anybody point me out how can I test the existence of the /sth/ url? Why do I get 404 instead of 200 ?

I went through on many pages about testing, but I still unable to find the mistake.

```
*
|
\---main.py
|
\---tests/
     |
     \--------test_view.py
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
#main.py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/sth/')
def hi():
    return 'HI\n'

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run()
```

In another terminal you do an easy request e.g.

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/sth/')

assert r.status_code == 200
```

Or you do it the Flask native way:
`test_example.py`

```
@pytest.fixture()
def app():
    app = create_app()
    app.config.update({
        "TESTING": True,
    })

    # other setup can go here

    yield app

    # clean up / reset resources here


@pytest.fixture()
def client(app):
    return app.test_client()



def yourtest(client):
    response = client.get("/sth/")
    assert response.request.path == "/index"
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

using this command in your CLI
`pytest test_example.py::yourtest`

I didn't test it yet.

My sources:

https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/usage.html
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/testing/

Comment: This isn't a correct solution, flask has a built in test client you can use that can simulate the server running from unit tests without having to launch the server.

Comment: @barryodev it is a correct solution! Just not with flask. Added the flask solution too.

Comment: You've changed your answer to address the error I raised...

Comment: @gerrel93 : I read a lot about this create_app(), however, I could not wtrite it, make it work. In this setup how would You do that?

Comment: put the `create_app()` in your main, it's just a design pattern. see here under Factories: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/patterns/appfactories/

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is with how you're creating a new app in your unit test when you call `app = Flask(__name__)`.

If you import your app variable into your unit test (I can't say how to do this exactly without seeing your project layout) but the below code should work if they're in the same directory.

```
from main import app

class TestSthView:
    def test_sth_returns_ok(self):
        c = app.test_client()
        resp = c.get('/sth/')

        assert resp.request.path == '/sth/'
        assert resp.status_code == 200
```

Comment: The root directory contains the main.py file and the tests directory which contains the test_view.py file. I updated the original question with this info.